# turpentine for varnish recently viewed products not working

Tags: magento-1.9, varnish, turpentine, recently-viewed

I am running turpentine 0.7.10 on Magento CE 1.9.3.7.
The recently viewed products block at the bottom of my list pages displays products from other customers sessions when varnish is on.
I saw a lot of discussion about this but nothing seems to resolve this, is this a known bug? Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a problem with **access** parameter in your ESI block definition in layout file (assuming you've not edited more files, it should be app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/turpentine_esi.xml)

The definition for this block should be something like this...

```
<action method="setEsiOptions">
    <params>
        <access>private</access>
        <flush_events>
            <catalog_controller_product_view/>
        </flush_events>
    </params>
</action>
```

If this is not working then you'd check what is your block name for *Recently viewed products* in your project layout files & validate it is the same (and the parent layout handle matches also) as defined in turpentine layout file. For instance:

```
<!-- fixes issues with 'recently viewed products' in CE 1.9's RWD theme -->
<catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
    <reference name="left.reports.product.viewed">
            <action method="setEsiOptions">
                <params>
                    <access>private</access>
                    <flush_events>
                        <catalog_controller_product_view/>
                    </flush_events>
                </params>
            </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
```

Comment: thank you i am using magneto's RWD theme so it should all be set properly

Comment: @yehuda are you sure you're using plain rwd?

Comment: @Haim yes it is